# How to Pin only the last child of the CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Suppose I have the following .xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
                <!--ToolBar here-->
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <!-- scrolls with the recycler view - may have different heights -->
            <PageTitleHere
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"/>

            <!-- This view pins on top when scrolling -->
            <AViewThatShouldPinOnTopOnScroll
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want that only the last child of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` pins to the top when scrolling. The problem is that if I leave the xml as it is, its children will all be placed on top of it, overlaying each other (because `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inherits `FrameLayout`)

Knowing that the height of `AViewThatShouldPinOnTopOnScroll` may vary, how can I achieve what I want by only editing the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this behavior, the `AViewThatShouldPinOnTopOnScroll` requires to be a direct child of the `AppBarLayout`; i.e. get it out of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`; and no need to the `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` as it's not a part of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` anymore:

The XML structure now:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
            <!--ToolBar here-->
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <!-- scrolls with the recycler view - may have different heights -->
        <PageTitleHere/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    
    <!-- This view pins on top when scrolling -->
    <AViewThatShouldPinOnTopOnScroll/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Demo

The yellow is the  `AViewThatShouldPinOnTopOnScroll`

[image]

Comment: Can you help me on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72685383/11560810)

Comment: @vivekmodi Something challenging to have the content overlap with the Toolbar. it worth a try

Comment: I tried some code, but it's not working.

Comment: @Zain can you share code for this solution? I tried the structure you shared above. But couldn't get it working...

Comment: @Jason [HYG](https://pastebin.com/Q2iThJBC)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example to solve the problem is:

```xml
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <!-- scrolls -->
        <Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />
        <!-- pins -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </AppBarLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```